# Docker error during connect when connected via VPN (Windows)

Tags: docker

I have Windows7, installed dockertoolbox, created several images and ran several containers. All good.

Today I was working from home using Cisco VPN and docker container failed.
[image]

If I disconnect VPN it works.

**How can I make docker work with VPN?**

Comment: It depends. Have you tried to start container after VPN is established? Did it worked then?

Comment: docker commands fail if vpn is on

Comment: Looks like cisco driver interferes with docker (bridge)whatever driver on windows.